# Find data in folders and give feedback about missing data

Tags: r, directory, feedback

I have a R-script to create several small parts of a big dataset (actually a dataset of Europe). We need these small parts (tiles) to edit these tiles more easily than it would be with one big dataset.

Now I have 1 windows folder and in this folder I have 966 auto-generated folders - each one with 4 datasets (I hope at least it is 4). We need to know if there are exactly these 4 datasets in the folders and if some dataset is missing we need to know which one. The code you can see below is creating the folders. Its posted just to let you know the structures.

```
in_file <- "P:/High_Resolution_Layers/Forest... .tif/2015/TCD_2015_020m_eu_03035_d04_full/TCD_2015_020m_eu_03035_d04_full.tif"


for (t in 1:length(tiles)){

  tileID <- tiles[t]

  out_dir <- file.path(output_dir,tileID)
  # out_dir_tmp <- file.path(out_dir, "tmp")
  if(!exists(out_dir)) {dir.create(out_dir, recursive = T)}
  # if(!exists(out_dir)) {dir.create(out_dir_tmp, recursive = T)}

  # tmp_file <- file.path(out_dir_tmp, paste0(tileID, "_HRL_Forest.tif")) ## <- ändern ("_HRL_Forest.tif", _clc_2012.tif, _clc_2018.tif, _slope.tif)
  out_file <- file.path(out_dir, paste0(tileID, "_HRL_Forest.tif")) ## <- ändern ("_HRL_Forest.tif", _clc_2012.tif, _clc_2018.tif, _slope.tif)

  cmd <- paste("gdalwarp",
               "-overwrite",
               "-s_srs EPSG:3035",
               "-t_srs EPSG:3035",
               "-r near",
               "-q",
               "-tr 20 20",
               "-te ", tile_list[t,3],tile_list[t,4],tile_list[t,3]+100000, tile_list[t,4]+100000,
               "-tap",
               "-of GTiff",
               in_file,
               out_file)

  system(osgeo, input=cmd)

  # cmd <- sprintf('gdal_translate -ot Byte -a_nodata 255 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" %s %s', tmp_file, out_file)
  # system(osgeo, input=cmd)

  # unlink(out_dir_tmp,recursive=T)
}
```

Comment: Having code here is a good thing, but I confess I have little desire to run something that generates almost 1000 folders and files within each. Just as much, your problem does not need `gdalwarp` to get to the source of your question. Can you adapt/reduce the problem to check for 3 folders with 2-4 text files each? The trick to having more people look at it is to make it easily reproducible, and the venn overlap of folks with `gdalwarp` installed and people on SO may not be huge. Also, what have you tried for the verification automation?

Comment: "Can you adapt/reduce the problem to check for 3 folders with 2-4 text files each?"  --> No, we need exactly this structure. 926 folders with several files (up to 10 files). "what have you tried for the verification automation?" --> I tried it with the following expressions: list.files(path = "T:/Processing/2734_EEA_HRL2018_Lot1/02_Interim_Products/LOT1_input_tiles", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE,
           full.names = FALSE, recursive = TRUE,
           ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = TRUE, no.. = FALSE)  But max write restrictions are limiting it and i dont know if sth is missing

Comment: I think my answer addresses my point, but to be clear: I was not asking if you could change your actual requirements, I was suggesting you could simplify how you ask the question to make it *minimal*. And since we don't have any files to "play" and test with, it is also not a *working* example. You may see people request this as a "MWE", also phrased as a fully reproducible (but still minimal) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make up a structure and list of files.

- directories `A` through `D`
- each directory must have files `a.tif` though `c.tif`

Since all dirs must have the same files within them, we can do a cartesian/`outer` join of them:

```r
dirs <- LETTERS[1:4]
files_each_dir <- paste0(letters[1:3], ".tif")
(all_files <- outer(dirs, files_each_dir, file.path))
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
# [1,] "A/a.tif" "A/b.tif" "A/c.tif"
# [2,] "B/a.tif" "B/b.tif" "B/c.tif"
# [3,] "C/a.tif" "C/b.tif" "C/c.tif"
# [4,] "D/a.tif" "D/b.tif" "D/c.tif"
```

Since we don't need a `matrix`, I'll unlist them and then create the dirs/files:

```r
c(all_files)
#  [1] "A/a.tif" "B/a.tif" "C/a.tif" "D/a.tif" "A/b.tif" "B/b.tif" "C/b.tif"
#  [8] "D/b.tif" "A/c.tif" "B/c.tif" "C/c.tif" "D/c.tif"
for (d in dirs) dir.create(d)
for (p in all_files) writeLines(p, p)
```

### All expected files exist

```r
(files_found <- list.files(pattern = "*.tif", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE))
#  [1] "./A/a.tif" "./A/b.tif" "./A/c.tif" "./B/a.tif" "./B/b.tif" "./B/c.tif"
#  [7] "./C/a.tif" "./C/b.tif" "./C/c.tif" "./D/a.tif" "./D/b.tif" "./D/c.tif"
### remove the leading "./"
(files_found <- gsub("^\\./", "", files_found))
#  [1] "A/a.tif" "A/b.tif" "A/c.tif" "B/a.tif" "B/b.tif" "B/c.tif" "C/a.tif"
#  [8] "C/b.tif" "C/c.tif" "D/a.tif" "D/b.tif" "D/c.tif"
all(all_files %in% files_found)
# [1] TRUE
all_files[!all_files %in% files_found]
# character(0)
```

Test a missing file:

```r
file.remove("B/c.tif")
# [1] TRUE
files_found <- list.files(pattern = "*.tif", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
files_found <- gsub("^\\./", "", files_found)
all_files[!all_files %in% files_found]
# [1] "B/c.tif"
```

Note: we do not use `files_each_dir` for any of the follow-on tests. It is only needed if we expect a fixed-set of filenames.

### Count files within each dir

If the filenames might be different, then we can count the number of files in each directory, irrespective of the actual names.

```r
(len3 <- lengths(split(files_found, sapply(strsplit(files_found, "[/\\]"), `[[`, 1))) == 3)
#     A     B     C     D 
#  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 
names(len3)[ !len3 ]
# [1] "B"
```

### File contents

If you need to test the contents such that some condition is true, try something like this. Here, I'm using simple shell command `grep`, but any function (R or shell) that takes a path and returns something you need (size, property, etc) should work.

```r
func <- function(path) length(system2("grep", c("-lE", "'[a-z]'", path), stdout = TRUE)) > 0
(proper_contents <- sapply(files_found, func))
# A/a.tif A/b.tif A/c.tif B/a.tif B/b.tif C/a.tif C/b.tif C/c.tif D/a.tif D/b.tif 
#    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE 
# D/c.tif 
#    TRUE
```

Let's change one file's contents to test:

```r
writeLines("123", "D/a.tif")
proper_contents <- sapply(files_found, func)
# Warning in system2("grep", c("-lE", "'[a-z]'", path), stdout = TRUE) :
#   running command '"grep" -lE '[a-z]' D/a.tif' had status 1
names(proper_contents)[ !proper_contents ]
# [1] "D/a.tif"
```